# SwiftUI: How to call a function in ContentView?

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I'm trying to call a function that takes a value and outputs a string. However, the code in content view kept giving me this error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    //properties
    var co2 = 400
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(airQuality()) //where the error occurs, I'm trying to print the result here
            .font(.custom("Devanagari Sangam MN", size:50))
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .offset(y:300)
    }
    
    //function I'm trying to call
    func airQuality(){
        if co2 > 1000 &&  co2 < 4000{
            print("Bad")
        }
        else if co2 >= 4000 {
            print("Caution")
        }
        else {
            print("Good")
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?? Thank you so much!

Comment: The function needs to return a `String`. `func airQuality() -> String {...}` and instead of `print(...)` use `return "Bad"`

Comment: Omg thank you so much!!! That worked! I'm new to this language, and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of doing this:

Since you are not changing the values, then better use let, no need for var or function.

### Way 1:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var co2: Int = 400

    var body: some View {
        
        AirView(co2: co2).padding()
        
        Button("co2 = 400") { co2 = 400 }.padding()
        Button("co2 = 2000") { co2 = 2_000 }.padding()
        Button("co2 = 5000") { co2 = 5_000 }.padding()

    }

}
```

---

```
struct AirView: View {

    let co2: Int
    private let airQuality: String
    
    init(co2: Int) {
        
        self.co2 = co2

        if (co2 > 1_000) && (co2 < 4_000) {
            self.airQuality = "Bad"
        }
        else if (co2 >= 4_000) {
            self.airQuality = "Caution"
        }
        else {
            self.airQuality = "Good"
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        Text("co2 is: " + co2.description + " " + airQuality)

    }

}
```

---

### Way 2:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var co2: Int = 400

    var body: some View {
        
        Text("co2 is: " + co2.description + " " + co2Function(co2: co2)).padding()
        
        Button("co2 = 400") { co2 = 400 }.padding()
        Button("co2 = 2000") { co2 = 2_000 }.padding()
        Button("co2 = 5000") { co2 = 5_000 }.padding()

    }
    
    
    func co2Function(co2: Int) -> String {

        if (co2 > 1_000) && (co2 < 4_000) {
            return "Bad"
        }
        else if (co2 >= 4_000) {
            return "Caution"
        }
        else {
            return "Good"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!!! The values are going to change, but here I'm just testing it out. :)) So my ultimate goal is to be able to import the data measured by different sensors, so the values will be constantly changing. I guess once I get there, my biggest problem would be importing/fetching the data. I have zero clue on how to code that. XD

Comment: @EricHuang:  It is not suggestion, It is the answer of your asked question! with your question up that is the right answer, there is no values but there is a value, and that is **co2**, if you change it from ContentView then AirView would change as well, I think you misunderstood between changing incoming value and the value inside of View! your Value inside AirView is not changing, but it will change once you change it from ContentView! these are 2 different things! I answered in 2 deferent way for you.

Comment: Yup I meant to say thanks for the solution haha. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can't call a function directly but the hack is to let it return an empty string and include it in a Text.

Text("Bla bla bla " + MyFunc())